# Add a string to a column only when the value matches a condition in pyspark

Tags: datetime, pyspark

I got a date column in string format in a PySpark dataframe in below format.

```
| Date |
| -------- |
| 3/28/2023|
```

and want my output to be:

```
| Date |
| -------- |
| 2023-03-28|
```

I replaced the  '/' symbol to '-' and convert the string to date format.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F 
df = df.withColumn("Date", F.regexp_replace('Date', '/', '-'))\
        .withColumn("Date", F.date_format(F.to_date(F.col("Date"),"MM-dd-yyyy"), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

But I got below error:

```
SparkUpgradeException: You may get a different result due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: Fail to parse '3-28-2023' in the new parser. You can set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy to LEGACY to restore the behavior before Spark 3.0, or set to CORRECTED and treat it as an invalid datetime string.
Caused by: DateTimeParseException: Text '3-28-2023' could not be parsed at index 0
```

So to avoid that, I added below line to the code where it adds '0' at the begining of the string and it executed successfully.

```
df = df.withColumn("Date", F.regexp_replace('Date', '/', '-'))\
       .withColumn('Date', F.concat(F.lit("0"), F.col('Date')))\
       .withColumn("Date", F.date_format(F.to_date(F.col("Date"),"MM-dd-yyyy"), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

Now, I want to add this zero conditionally such that if only one digit exists before first '-' in the string. I got stuck here because I am not sure if regex expression can aggregate how many values are present before a character. Please help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark will automatically handles the **`Zeros`** by specifying `MM` as month.

**`Example:`**

```
#sample data
#+----------+
#|      Date|
#+----------+
#| 3/28/2023|
#|04/28/2023|
#+----------+
#set this legacy parameter for timeparserpolicy
spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")
df.withColumn("Date",F.date_format(F.to_date(col("Date"),"MM/dd/yyyy"), 'yyyy-MM-dd')).show(10,False)

#+----------+
#|Date      |
#+----------+
#|2023-03-28|
#|2023-04-28|
#+----------+
```